# Copy constructor not called when using boost::bind, boost::shared_ptr, and boost::thread together

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I am creating a new `boost::thread` using `boost::bind`, and storing it in a `boost::shared_ptr`.
I am passing a function and argument to the `boost::thread`, but when the thread is started, it does not correctly call the copy constructor for the function argument.

The thread creation method I'm using is a very common Boost pattern, so I don't think that's where the problem is:

```
void myclass::myfunc() {
   Workflow wfOriginal;
   boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(
       new boost::thread(boost::bind(&myclass::anotherfunc, this, wfOriginal)));
}
// ...
void myclass::anotherfunc(Workflow wfCopied) {
   // Doing something
}
```

I am trying to copy the `Workflow` from `myfunc()` to `anotherfunc()`.
`Workflow` contains a collection, so I have provided a copy constructor that copies the elements inside the existing collection to the new `Workflow`.

Unfortunately, when `anotherfunc()` is called by the new thread, the collection inside `wfCopied` is empty!
I can tell that the `Workflow` object was partially copied, because other members like strings and ints have been copied, but the elements in the collection have not.

I have verified that the copy constructor works correctly by testing it with this code:

```
Workflow wf;
// ... insert some elements into wf...
Workflow wf1 = wf;
// wf1 has the same elements
```

I want to emphasize that my tests showed me that `Workflow`'s copy constructor works fine.
But for completeness, here is the copy constructor for `Workflow`:

```
Workflow::Workflow(const Workflow& workflow) {
    this->_id = workflow._id;
    (this->_tasks).clear();
    Workflow::TaskCollectionConstIterator it;
    for (it = (this->_tasks).begin(); it < (this->_tasks).end(); it++)
        (this->_tasks).push_back(*it);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this your real code?  use of `wf` both as a parameter name on `myclass::anotherFunc` and as a class member seems suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your copy constructor is flawed. You're copying from your empty vector to your vector. Which results in nothing being copied.

I think you mean:

```
for (it = (workflow->_tasks).begin(); it < (workflow->_tasks).end(); it++)
    (this->_tasks).push_back(*it);
```

Comment: OK well, the problem was another one, :) anyway, this was a bug too!! THANKS for your help... what a stupid bug.... did I really make such a stupid mistake?

Comment: I just compiled some test code that conceptually does what you're trying. I get the expected results. Perhaps there is something else that is being missed in your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what constructor initialization list is? And why exactly do you clear container in constructor?

```
Workflow::Workflow(const Workflow& workflow): _id(workflow._id),
    _tasks(workflow._tasks.begin(), workflow._tasks.end()) 
{}
```